# EC2 Instance Connection From Different MAC

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have EC2 micro instance on AWS, I was connecting (SSH) to this instance fine through MAC. My Mac hard drive has failed and I do not have the `keypair` stored anywhere.

I tried to generate the different `keypair` and downloaded the `.pem file` to different mac and tried connecting. But it comes with:

> public Key (permission denied).

It actually does not show the correct fingerprint also.

How do I connect to EC2 instance using new laptop without having original `".pem"`file (which was created when instance was provisioned).

Answer (score 1):

You need to create new key-pair as following:-

1. From your AWS console stop the instance in question
2. Create a snapshot of the instance
3. Create a duplicate instance from the resulting snapshot and create a new Key Pair.

More Details Here : https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=102074

Answer (score 0):

An instance can only be associated with a key pair only at launch time (either to an existing key pair or by creating a new key pair). that means if you lose the key pair then you won't be able to generate another one for that already running instance or associate it with an already existing key pair. To urgently address your issue, you may try to do the following:-

1. From your WAS console stop the instance in question
2. Create a snapshot of the instance
3. Create a duplicate instance from the resulting snapshot and create a new Key Pair.

Once the instance is up and running, you would be able to log into the new instance using the new key pair. The new instance is identical in every aspect to the original instance and you can carry on your work from there. If you were using an elastic IP, then dissociate it from the old instance and associate it with the new instance and make sure to update DNS as well. If you are happy you can then terminate the old instance.

If you require any further assistance, please let me know. I hope this helps.

Comment: Also make sure to save the new key pair somewhere safe and or make a duplicate :-)